# Having confusion with if ledder containg array in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;
//const int n=20;

class cofee
{     
   //public:
   int i;
   //int n=20;
   int price[20];
   //int totalprice[n];

   public:
   void getprice()
   {    
      if(i=1)
      {
         price[i]=10;
         cout<<"price is :"<<price[i]<<""\n;
      }
      else if(i=2)
      {
         price[i]=20;
         cout<<"price is :"<<price[i];
      }
      else if(i=2)
      {
         price[i]=30;
         cout<<"price is :"<<price[i];
      }
      else
      {
         cout<<"\n";
      }
   }

   void total()
   {
      int sum=0;
      int n=3;
      for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
      {
         sum = sum+price[i];
      }
      cout<<"total is:"<<sum;
   }
};

int main()
{
   cofee c;
   int i;

   do
   {
      cout<<"enter your choice";
      cout<<"\n1.plain cofee";
      cout<<"\n2.cold cofee";
      cout<<"\n3.farali cofee";
      cout<<"\n4.total";
      cout<<"\n5.quit";
      cout<<"\n";
      cin>>i;

      switch(i)
      {
         case 1 : c.getprice(); break;
         case 2 : c.getprice(); break;
         case 3 : c.getprice(); break;
         case 4 : c.total(); break;
         case 5 : break;
         default : cout<<"\nwrong cchoice";
      }
   }while(i!=5);

   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

i have tried almost everything i could but still its not giving proper output. neither its showing any error or warning.

in if else ledder price is not storing value for i=2 & 3. need help to solve it.

Comment: You have very basic errors in your code. It will be better for you work through some basic tutorials or text book examples on classes.

Comment: There are lots of little problems in your code (as @RSahu already pointed out). You should start small and try to understand the meaning of each line or subsection in your code. Then try out that line/subsection in a smaller program to make sure that it actually does what you thought it does (you will probably be surprised). Here is a hint that might help: The variable `i` in your `main()` function is not the same as the member `i` in class `cofee` even though they have the name. Are you thinking that assigning a value to `i` in main will also assign the same value to the `i` in class `cofee`?

Comment: Hint#2: Read about the [difference between `==` and `=` in C++](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/162256/in-c-and-c-what-methods-can-prevent-accidental-use-of-the-assignment-where).

Answer (score 0):

When you use (=) in a if, you don't COMPARE the values, you actually give him the value, so the first "if" will always be true. If they were all "if" and not "else if" they would all be true(use "==" instead)! Also, for your variables, if you don't specify them to be public, they will be private by default.